# How to author fla files?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

Be prepared :-) This question may be very dumb, as I have *zero* experience with Flash (although I have programming and developer skills in other areas as .NET, Java, Web Development, SQL etc)

I've tried to Google it but still I am confused.

My main question: Is an .fla file a source or it is a compiled output?
If it is a source then how to author it?

I see it is a .zip archive with .fla extansion. My guess is it must be a source, then why I can not open it with FlashBuilder? I've installer FlashBuilder 4.5.1 (that is what I have) and it does not even offer this extension in the File/Import Flash Builder Project dialog window.

I've also tried File/Open File. I got modal error message window: just get this message "Windows cannot find 'Flash'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again."
In Preferences/File Associations for FLA Adobe Flash Editor (default) is selected.

It is a Windows 7 machine, with a fresh Flash Builder 4.5.1 install.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

.fla's are opened in Flash Pro.

It mostly contains assets (bitmaps, sounds, animations ...). It may contain code (i hate coding in it, but some people do, often for little programs). And thus you may compile a workable .swf (= compiled code) with only a swf and flash pro.
Fla's also can refer to external code files (.as). They can inherit an external Class.

I do work with flash pro to make all my designs (in an fla) and do all my code in [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/).

Lots of people do there code in FlashBuilder, and embed their assets (at compilation) with it. An thus do not use any .fla.